# Split command to chunk a large CSV - with new line character

Tags: files, csv, split

I'm splitting a large CSV file with small chunks using the `split` command. Each file should contain **1000 rows only.**

The command I used is,

```bsh
cat large.csv | split -a3 -l1000  --filter='gzip > $FILE.gz' - small.csv_
```

It actually worked, but the problem is when I have a new line character in my CSV and its from line number 1000, then it breaks everything.

EG:

```
Row no 1000:

1001 | my_first_name | my_last_name | Address: 2001,appartment
my_city | my_country | pin-610156
```

Column number 4 is having a new line char and its occupying 2 lines. The split command considered that line 1000 will end at `Address: 2001,appartment` and the next line will go to a new file. This breaks 2 files.

1. The file with 1000'th line - not having rest of the columns (let say file:10)
2. The next file(file 11) will start with `my_city` - First 4 columns are not here.

When I load these files into a  database, these files will give problems.

Is there any way or workaround that can solve this?

Comment: Is there any way to know that this line is problematic? For example, do all your lines have the same number of fields so we can detect cases where there are fewer fields on a line because of the newline character? Can we assume all csv entries should have exactly 6 fields and that fields are defined by `|`?

Comment: During the CSV creation (Its from a database, the data is like a forum-based data), so there are a lot of rows that have new line char. And if we dont have access to that export process, so I have to solve it in a different way

Comment: With some luck the data comes from e.g. Windows and has `\r\n` as record separator. Anything nice from `cat -A`? Please also answer the question whether `|` is always the column separator and if there is a fixed number of columns in all cases.

Comment: @bhuvanesh how can we know when a row is not complete? How can we separate good rows from bad rows? As I asked before: do you know how many fields per row?

Comment: @bhuvanesh aparently this is not a valid csv.

Comment: @JJoao - Yeah, thats why I'm trying to fix it. Since its a dump from a database, so I shouldn't expect clean data :)

Comment: Could you share an example to test it?

Comment: This does not look like CSV _at all_.  It looks like table-formatted data. There are no proper quoting of fields with special characters and there is padding with spaces around the "delimiters".  You can't treat this as CSV at all. Having the database export the data as CSV would be preferable.

Comment: If you share an example input file, I think to have a solution for you